# Unable to export mysql database running on aws RDS using phpmyadmin running in docker

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL database server running on AWS RDS. and I have phpMyAdmin running on one of my EC2 instances in docker-container with the arbitrary server option. I'm able to connect to database using the phpMyAdmin web panel, but when I try to export the database, it throws an error: couldn't download network error.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Issue Resolved. it was nginx issue i have added below code in location block in nginx and now it's working.
       proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;